# How to target a specific div by using selectors (no js)

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

```
<div class="topPart-box">
    <div class="topPart-content">
        <h1>Fanis Enterprice</h1>
        <div class="nav-dropdown">
            <img src="icon.png" width="50px;" height="50px;" alt="nav-icon" class="nav-icon">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu"></div>
</div>
```

I basically want that whenever someone hovers on the `.nav-dropdown` class, I want to display the `.dropdown-menu` class. I'm having trouble trying to select the `.dropdown-menu` class.

Comment: With your current markup, you cannot do this with CSS, since there is no way to target an element that is not in the same parent element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without JS that's only possible if you move the `.dropdown-menu` div into the same parent as the `.nav-dropdown` element, i.e. into the `topPart-content`div. In this case you can use a sibling selector as follows:

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
}

.nav-dropdown:hover + .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="topPart-box">
  <div class="topPart-content">
    <h1>Fanis Enterprice</h1>
    <div class="nav-dropdown">
      <img src="icon.png" width="50px;" height="50px;" alt="nav-icon" class="nav-icon">
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">TEST</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the markup to be like this:

```
<div class="nav-dropdown">

    <div class="dropdown-heading">
       <img src="icon.png" width="50px;" height="50px;" alt="nav-icon" class="nav-icon">
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown-menu"></div>

</div>
```